# Use a pageIterator with the WithAppOnly() request option

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I'm trying to build a .NET8 console app which will do some Microsoft Graph calls using application only permissions. the app uses a certificate to get a token and should authenticate itself without any user prompt.

The code below works as I'm able to set the WithAppOnly option to work only with application permissions :

```
var devices = await graphServiceClient.DeviceManagement.ManagedDevices.GetAsync(r => r.Options.WithAppOnly());
```

But if I try to iterate through all pages it seems that the PageIterator ignores the WithAppOnly option and therefore I get the following error :

> IDW10502: An MsalUiRequiredException was thrown due to a challenge for
> the user.

Here's the code I use to iterate :

```
var devicelist = new List<DeviceModel>();

var pageIterator = PageIterator<ManagedDevice, ManagedDeviceCollectionResponse>.CreatePageIterator(graphServiceClient, devices, (device) =>
{
    devicelist.Add(DeviceModelMapper.MapFromManagedDevice(device));
    return true;
    });
await pageIterator.IterateAsync();
```

How can I add the withAppOnly request option to the iterator ? Or can I add the WithAppOnly option as default in my graph client ?

And in the worst case how can I iterate through pages without the iterator ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to configure request options for subsequent request?

```
var pageIterator = PageIterator<ManagedDevice, ManagedDeviceCollectionResponse>.CreatePageIterator(graphServiceClient, devices, (device) =>
{
    devicelist.Add(DeviceModelMapper.MapFromManagedDevice(device));
    return true;
},
requestInfo=>
{
    var requestOptions = new List<IRequestOption>();
    requestOptions.WithAppOnly();
    requestInfo.AddRequestOptions(requestOptions);
    return requestInfo;
});
```